# Extract the required XML message in the form of string

Tags: python, xml, soap

I am getting below xml SOAP response from an API. I am using "requests" library to hit the url of API.

SOAP response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:AvailabilityResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.derbysoft.com/doorway" Status="Successful" Token="87348a9665ffc984abf37329">
        <ns2:Availabilities>
            <ns2:Availability CurrencyCode="USD" HotelCode="HY-CHIRC">
                <ns2:GuestCount AdultCount="1" ChildCount="0"/>
                <ns2:RoomTypes>
                    <ns2:RoomType RoomTypeCode="KING" RoomTypeName="1 King Bed">
                        <ns2:RoomTypeDescription>1 King Bed; 1 Grand Bed:Ihome Station:Large Plasma Tv:; Large Workdesk:Comp Gym</ns2:RoomTypeDescription>
                    </ns2:RoomType>
                    <ns2:RoomType RoomTypeCode="DLXK" RoomTypeName="High Floor King">
                        <ns2:RoomTypeDescription>High Floor King; Guaranteed High Floor-25th and Up:350 Sq Ft; 1 King Grand Bed:Oversized Workdesk:Free Wifi</ns2:RoomTypeDescription>
                    </ns2:RoomType>
                    <ns2:RoomType RoomTypeCode="VW1K" RoomTypeName="Premium View King">
                        <ns2:RoomTypeDescription>Premium View King; 1 King Bed:Ihome Station:Large Plasma Tv:; Large Workdesk:Comp Gym</ns2:RoomTypeDescription>
                    </ns2:RoomType>
                    <ns2:RoomType RoomTypeCode="CLBK" RoomTypeName="Regency Club King">
                        <ns2:RoomTypeDescription>Regency Club King; Comp Contl Breakfast:Hors D Oeuvres and Dessert:; Exclusive Club Lounge With View</ns2:RoomTypeDescription>
                    </ns2:RoomType>
                    <ns2:RoomType RoomTypeCode="QNQN" RoomTypeName="2 Queen Beds">
                        <ns2:RoomTypeDescription>2 Queen Beds; 2 Queen Grand Beds:Ihome Station:Plasma Tv:; Large Workdesk:Comp Gym</ns2:RoomTypeDescription>
                    </ns2:RoomType>
                    <ns2:RoomType RoomTypeCode="VW2Q" RoomTypeName="Premium View 2 Qen">
                        <ns2:RoomTypeDescription>Premium View 2 Qen; 2 Queen Beds:Ihome Station:Large Plasma Tv:; Large Workdesk:Comp Gym</ns2:RoomTypeDescription>
                    </ns2:RoomType>
                    <ns2:RoomType RoomTypeCode="JRSQ" RoomTypeName="Grand 2 Queens">
                        <ns2:RoomTypeDescription>Grand 2 Queens; Oversized Corner Room:2 Queen Beds:420 Sq Ft:; 2 Soft Chairs:Sml Table:Large Desk:Free Wifi</ns2:RoomTypeDescription>
                    </ns2:RoomType>
                    <ns2:RoomType RoomTypeCode="CLBD" RoomTypeName="Regency Club 2 Double Beds Bd">
                        <ns2:RoomTypeDescription>Regency Club 2 Double Beds Bd; Comp Contl Breakfast:Hors D Oeuvres and Dessert:; Exclusive Club Lounge With View</ns2:RoomTypeDescription>
                    </ns2:RoomType>
                    <ns2:RoomType RoomTypeCode="JRSK" RoomTypeName="Junior City View Suite">
                        <ns2:RoomTypeDescription>Junior City View Suite; Large Parlor With 1 King Bed Grand Bed:Sitting Area:; Oversize Couch:Large Desk:Plasma Tv</ns2:RoomTypeDescription>
                    </ns2:RoomType>
                    <ns2:RoomType RoomTypeCode="DLXD" RoomTypeName="High Fl 2 Double">
                        <ns2:RoomTypeDescription>High Fl 2 Double; Guaranteed High Floor-25th and Up:350 Sq Ft; 2 Double Beds:Oversized Workdesk:Free Wifi</ns2:RoomTypeDescription>
                    </ns2:RoomType>
                </ns2:RoomTypes>
                <ns2:RatePlans>
                    <ns2:RatePlan RatePlanCode="49584IPRTF" RatePlanName="Partner Rate">
                        <ns2:RatePlanDescription/>
                        <ns2:CancelPolicy NonRefundable="false">
                            <ns2:Description>CXL 24HRS PRIOR TO ARRIVAL TO AVOID 1NT PNLTY</ns2:Description>
                            <ns2:CancelPenalties>
                                <ns2:CancelPenalty MaxHoursBeforeCheckIn="24" MinHoursBeforeCheckIn="0" Nights="1" NoShow="false"/>
                                <ns2:CancelPenalty Nights="1" NoShow="true"/>
                            </ns2:CancelPenalties>
                        </ns2:CancelPolicy>
                    </ns2:RatePlan>
                    <ns2:RatePlan RatePlanCode="49584WPAWAF" RatePlanName="Bed And Breakfast">
                        <ns2:RatePlanDescription/>
                        <ns2:CancelPolicy NonRefundable="false">
                            <ns2:Description>CXL 24HRS PRIOR TO ARRIVAL TO AVOID 1NT PNLTY</ns2:Description>
                            <ns2:CancelPenalties>
                                <ns2:CancelPenalty MaxHoursBeforeCheckIn="24" MinHoursBeforeCheckIn="0" Nights="1" NoShow="false"/>
                                <ns2:CancelPenalty Nights="1" NoShow="true"/>
                            </ns2:CancelPenalties>
                        </ns2:CancelPolicy>
                    </ns2:RatePlan>
                </ns2:RatePlans>
                <ns2:RoomRates>
                    <ns2:RoomRate RatePlanCode="49584IPRTF" RoomTypeCode="KING">
                        <ns2:Rates>
                            <ns2:Rate AmountAfterTax="178.610" AmountBeforeTax="152.150" EffectiveDate="2016-05-13" ExpireDate="2016-05-14"/>
                        </ns2:Rates>
                    </ns2:RoomRate>
                    <ns2:RoomRate RatePlanCode="49584IPRTF" RoomTypeCode="DLXK">
                        <ns2:Rates>
                            <ns2:Rate AmountAfterTax="198.570" AmountBeforeTax="169.150" EffectiveDate="2016-05-13" ExpireDate="2016-05-14"/>
                        </ns2:Rates>
                    </ns2:RoomRate>
                    <ns2:RoomRate RatePlanCode="49584IPRTF" RoomTypeCode="VW1K">
                        <ns2:Rates>
                            <ns2:Rate AmountAfterTax="218.520" AmountBeforeTax="186.150" EffectiveDate="2016-05-13" ExpireDate="2016-05-14"/>
                        </ns2:Rates>
                    </ns2:RoomRate>
                    <ns2:RoomRate RatePlanCode="49584IPRTF" RoomTypeCode="CLBK">
                        <ns2:Rates>
                            <ns2:Rate AmountAfterTax="233.490" AmountBeforeTax="198.900" EffectiveDate="2016-05-13" ExpireDate="2016-05-14"/>
                        </ns2:Rates>
                    </ns2:RoomRate>
                    <ns2:RoomRate RatePlanCode="49584IPRTF" RoomTypeCode="QNQN">
                        <ns2:Rates>
                            <ns2:Rate AmountAfterTax="178.610" AmountBeforeTax="152.150" EffectiveDate="2016-05-13" ExpireDate="2016-05-14"/>
                        </ns2:Rates>
                    </ns2:RoomRate>
                    <ns2:RoomRate RatePlanCode="49584IPRTF" RoomTypeCode="VW2Q">
                        <ns2:Rates>
                            <ns2:Rate AmountAfterTax="218.520" AmountBeforeTax="186.150" EffectiveDate="2016-05-13" ExpireDate="2016-05-14"/>
                        </ns2:Rates>
                    </ns2:RoomRate>
                    <ns2:RoomRate RatePlanCode="49584IPRTF" RoomTypeCode="JRSQ">
                        <ns2:Rates>
                            <ns2:Rate AmountAfterTax="253.450" AmountBeforeTax="215.900" EffectiveDate="2016-05-13" ExpireDate="2016-05-14"/>
                        </ns2:Rates>
                    </ns2:RoomRate>
                    <ns2:RoomRate RatePlanCode="49584IPRTF" RoomTypeCode="CLBD">
                        <ns2:Rates>
                            <ns2:Rate AmountAfterTax="233.490" AmountBeforeTax="198.900" EffectiveDate="2016-05-13" ExpireDate="2016-05-14"/>
                        </ns2:Rates>
                    </ns2:RoomRate>
                    <ns2:RoomRate RatePlanCode="49584WPAWAF" RoomTypeCode="KING">
                        <ns2:Rates>
                            <ns2:Rate AmountAfterTax="208.540" AmountBeforeTax="177.650" EffectiveDate="2016-05-13" ExpireDate="2016-05-14"/>
                        </ns2:Rates>
                    </ns2:RoomRate>
                    <ns2:RoomRate RatePlanCode="49584WPAWAF" RoomTypeCode="DLXK">
                        <ns2:Rates>
                            <ns2:Rate AmountAfterTax="218.520" AmountBeforeTax="186.150" EffectiveDate="2016-05-13" ExpireDate="2016-05-14"/>
                        </ns2:Rates>
                    </ns2:RoomRate>
                    <ns2:RoomRate RatePlanCode="49584WPAWAF" RoomTypeCode="VW1K">
                        <ns2:Rates>
                            <ns2:Rate AmountAfterTax="238.480" AmountBeforeTax="203.150" EffectiveDate="2016-05-13" ExpireDate="2016-05-14"/>
                        </ns2:Rates>
                    </ns2:RoomRate>
                    <ns2:RoomRate RatePlanCode="49584WPAWAF" RoomTypeCode="JRSK">
                        <ns2:Rates>
                            <ns2:Rate AmountAfterTax="448.020" AmountBeforeTax="381.650" EffectiveDate="2016-05-13" ExpireDate="2016-05-14"/>
                        </ns2:Rates>
                    </ns2:RoomRate>
                    <ns2:RoomRate RatePlanCode="49584WPAWAF" RoomTypeCode="QNQN">
                        <ns2:Rates>
                            <ns2:Rate AmountAfterTax="198.570" AmountBeforeTax="169.150" EffectiveDate="2016-05-13" ExpireDate="2016-05-14"/>
                        </ns2:Rates>
                    </ns2:RoomRate>
                    <ns2:RoomRate RatePlanCode="49584WPAWAF" RoomTypeCode="DLXD">
                        <ns2:Rates>
                            <ns2:Rate AmountAfterTax="218.520" AmountBeforeTax="186.150" EffectiveDate="2016-05-13" ExpireDate="2016-05-14"/>
                        </ns2:Rates>
                    </ns2:RoomRate>
                    <ns2:RoomRate RatePlanCode="49584WPAWAF" RoomTypeCode="VW2Q">
                        <ns2:Rates>
                            <ns2:Rate AmountAfterTax="238.480" AmountBeforeTax="203.150" EffectiveDate="2016-05-13" ExpireDate="2016-05-14"/>
                        </ns2:Rates>
                    </ns2:RoomRate>
                    <ns2:RoomRate RatePlanCode="49584WPAWAF" RoomTypeCode="JRSQ">
                        <ns2:Rates>
                            <ns2:Rate AmountAfterTax="448.020" AmountBeforeTax="381.650" EffectiveDate="2016-05-13" ExpireDate="2016-05-14"/>
                        </ns2:Rates>
                    </ns2:RoomRate>
                </ns2:RoomRates>
            </ns2:Availability>
        </ns2:Availabilities>
    </ns2:AvailabilityResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Now, I just want CancelPolicy related to particular RatePlanCode only. Let's say, I just want CancelPolicy of RatePlanCode "49584WPAWAF" then it should return like this and this return XML should be in the form of string.

```
<ns2:CancelPolicy NonRefundable="false">
                            <ns2:Description>CXL 24HRS PRIOR TO ARRIVAL TO AVOID 1NT PNLTY</ns2:Description>
                            <ns2:CancelPenalties>
                                <ns2:CancelPenalty MaxHoursBeforeCheckIn="24" MinHoursBeforeCheckIn="0" Nights="1" NoShow="false"/>
                                <ns2:CancelPenalty Nights="1" NoShow="true"/>
                            </ns2:CancelPenalties>
                        </ns2:CancelPolicy>
```

How can I approach this problem. Please just don't mention the library I could use. Try to provide the solution by using that library. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following XPath to find `RatePlan` based on `RatePlanCode` attribute value, and then return child element `CancelPolicy` :

```
//ns2:RatePlan[@RatePlanCode='49584WPAWAF']/ns2:CancelPolicy
```

You can execute the XPath using `xml.etree`, or using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/installation.html)* as follow :

```
from lxml import etree

raw = '''your xml string here'''
root = etree.fromstring(raw)
ns = {'ns2': 'http://www.derbysoft.com/doorway'}
query = "//ns2:RatePlan[@RatePlanCode='49584WPAWAF']/ns2:CancelPolicy"
result = root.xpath(query, namespaces=ns)
print etree.tostring(result[0])
```

Comment: I don't want the namespaces: (xmlns:ns2="http://www.derbysoft.com/doorway" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/) in my result. How could I remove them?